# ANDROID JAVA: Activity doesn't start when the used SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I want to read value Integer of activity "Settings" in the service GPSTracker and use it there. I use this SharedPrefrences and confirming key input. If the data is validated that the application returns to class FullscreenActivity. 
This is the code responsible for this in activity Settings:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String NAME = "DISTANCE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=pref.edit();

    Edit1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSkan);
    accept= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSkan);
    accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (!Edit1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                value = Integer.parseInt(Edit1.getText().toString());
            editor.putInt("settings", value);
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed, value + " m", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

A code in GPSTracker like this:

```
      SharedPreferences pref;
```

(...)

```
    private int downloadSettings()
    {
        pref=context.getSharedPreferences("DISTANCE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        value = pref.getInt("settings",15); 

        return value;
    }
```

and a method call:

```
    int dist = downloadSettings();
```

When I run the apps I get two errors in the log:

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adam.mobileproject/com.example.adam.mobileproject.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.adam.mobileproject.GPSTracker.downloadSettings(GPSTracker.java:284)
            at com.example.adam.mobileproject.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:200)
            at com.example.adam.mobileproject.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: what is your line number `284` in `GPSTracker`

Comment: what is context there?

Comment: use this as value = pref.getInt("settings","");

Comment: It looks like `context` might be null.  How do you start the service?  Do you call `startService()`?

Comment: @rogerthatcode - My line 284 is:   pref=context.getSharedPreferences("DISTANCE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @ Talha Qamar - I can't, because the second argument is an Integer

Comment: change `Activity.MODE_PRIVATE` to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` .. tell me if it works

Comment: @rogerthatcode - still doesn't work

Comment: try put `pref=context.getSharedPreferences("DISTANCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` this line in your `onCreate()` method of class ..

Comment: still nothing - lines 40 and 41 in FullscreenActivity is:                                         `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lokal2);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext(),tv);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely that `context` is null.

However, just like the Activity class, the Service class extends Context, so you should be able to replace `context` with `this` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Try this:

```
private int downloadSettings()
{
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DISTANCE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    value = pref.getInt("settings",15); 

    return value;
}
```